# Real time data from CSV read in C++

Tags: c++

I need to read data from CSV file which is updated every second with a new data in the same cell and row.

What i mean is following :
For example i have 1 in the first row and cell then i have already 2 etc. But everything is changed in the same row and column.

```
struct Node
{
 double number;
}
void readData(vector<Node>&Values)
{
 Node Data;
 ifstream file("file.csv");
 if (file.good())
    cout << "file ok";
 file >> Data.number;
 Values.push_back(Data);
}
int main()
{
vector<Node>Values;
while (true)
 {
    readData(Values); 
    _sleep(1000);
 }
}
```

The problem i have is that it reads every second the new data but it saves in the vector the same number from the beginning. If the number was 1, it will save the same number hundreds times even if the number has been changed 10 times.

What should i change in the read file to work with the data which can be updated because the csv file is opened and updated, i can not close it? 
I am pretty sure that it can be done the problem i did not find any solution in the internet.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simplify the code as such;

```
double ReadData()
{
    double val;
    ifstream file("file.csv");
    if (!file.good())
    {// Check if valid, return Error Code
        return 0;
    }

    file >> val;
    return val;
}

int main()
{
    vector<double> values;
    while (true)
    {
        double retVal = ReadData();
        if (retVal == 0)
        {// Whatever you defined the error code as
            break;
        }

        values.push_back(retVal);
        _sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

and if you really want the structure I'd just return the data and add it to the structure in the main loop.

Comment: It works well but still the same problem i have it does not want to update the data. It saves all the time 1 even if i run the program 100 times.. The number changes after 10 seconds and even after 10 seconds it saves 1. It takes the first value and ignores any modifications in excel

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the file you are trying to read from, i.e the format and data. Why are you editing a CSV in excel ?

Comment: That is my fault i said excel.. I work with CSV file. I have a streaming information and it is uploaded every second but i can not save it in c++. I will try my best because i already tried hundreds of codes but still it does not work. I have already used macro in excel and saved there data. Now i have a problem with reading cells and rows from CSV. If you can, give me your mail and we can talk there because do not use this forum for 100 messages.

Answer (score -2):

Change from _sleep(1000) to _sleep(150